# Grease pencil is appearing infront of other objects

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, grease-pencil

my grease pencil is appearing infront of other objects, z pass is checked and stroke depth order is set to 3d location. In viewport everything appears to be fine, but as soon as i render the image strokes appear infront of the object
Blender file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/4asy6ckxvnnfuav/RoomWith_shader.blend/file

[image]
[image]

Comment: Showing just an image with the problem is not often enough. Please edit the question and add a screenshot of how it looks like in different view, how it is supposed to look like and if possible an example blend file with the issue.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for the reply, i edited the post to add image from another view, not sure how to upload a blender file, ill add it to my post as soon as ill figure it out

Comment: Blender file added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 **View Layers**.

The names of the View Layers are **"View Layer"**, **"Masking"** and **"Cube"**. You are using **Compositing** for the final render with View Layers - **"Masking"** and **"Cube"**

If compositing is disabled and only **"View Layer"** is rendered - there is no issue with the baked grease pencil shadow.

When comparing all View Layers - it seems there is only one difference in the render settings that may have caused the issue:

[image]

The **Z value pass** is **turned off** for both **"Masking"** and **"Cube"** View Layers

[image]

Enabling that option for both **"Masking"** and **"Cube"** View Layers seems to resolve the problem when rendering with Compositing enabled.

[image]

I hope that helped.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Nwarp, you're welcome.